# Insert into mysql table using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert some data to my MySql table using C# but I'm facing some problems
I've added the MySql.Data.MySqlClient reference.

I've gone through some tutorials on the web and I found some codes like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`; however when I try to write this code it does not show up any idea why? It only shows `.Add`.

I've created a simple table 'inf' which has a id, name and surname where id is the primary key and it's on `autoIncrement`. My code is as follows:

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=insertdeneme;Uid=****;Pwd=********;";
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString);
mcon.Open();

string cmdText = "INSERT INTO inf VALUES (null, @name, @surname)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, mcon);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", txtsurname.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The program compiles however when I press on the button I get the following error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

When I remove the null from values I get:

> Column 'name' cannot be null

So what do you think is the problem with the code?

Edited: I have one form, two text boxes and a button (txtname.text,txtsurname.text, btn.register). I added the `mysql.data.mysqlclient` reference.

I created a database using phpMyAdmin, and in my table I have id name and surname where id is primary and on auto increment with 11 digits and name surname are type of varchar with the limitation of 255 chars and the rest of the code are above.

What I also don't understand is why am I not able to use `addwithvalue`.

> Error 1   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'addWithValue' and no extension method 'addWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\FOREVER\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\InsertInto1\InsertInto1\Form1.cs 63  32  InsertInto1

Comment: When your parameter is null value try setting it to DBNull.Value

Comment: Did you try @Palak.Maheria suggestion?

Comment: yes, is it possible that my textboxes return null? even if I type in? everything seems normal and whatever I try the execute reader gives the error name column can not be null

Answer (score 4):

I think your giving id  is autoincrement, if your mention the autoincrement means not mention the `null value` you should must remove the null,..

**update:1**

```
string cmdText= "INSERT INTO inf(name, surname) VALUES (@name, @surname)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, mcon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: when I do that I get this error " Column 'name' cannot be null"

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do this but It seems that I am not able to use addwithValue method.. I don't have it .. I don't know why

Comment: in the tutorials I saw on the web, that method is being used and it works perfectly but when I type in parameters. I have Add not AddwithValue

Answer (score 3):

> id is the primary key and it's on autoIncrement

Then don't try to insert an `id`.  *Especially* don't try to insert a `null` value into a primary key.  Since you're only inserting data into two of the table's columns, specify those columns:

```
INSERT INTO inf (name, surname) VALUES (@name, @surname)
```

Comment: when I do that I get this error " Column 'name' cannot be null"

Comment: @user3456351: What are the values being inserted?  Does `txtname.Text` have a value?  Since this is MySQL, are the parameter markers different?  Maybe it should be `?name` instead of `@name`?

Comment: I don't know,let me try

Comment: @user3456351: "Didn't work" isn't very specific.  It seems like there's some information you're not sharing with us.  Can you update the question with the table definition?  What happens when you attempt this query directly instead of through code?  First define a working query, then add it to the application.